# Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1:

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using a remote server to running my python script, it has NVIDIA's and I want to use it to speed up the processing time.

I have downloaded the following packages as it's described in this tutorial:

```
tensorflow-gpu            2.4.1           h30adc30_0.conda
tensorflow                2.4.1           gpu_py39h8236f22_0.conda          
cudatoolkit               10.1.243        nvidia
cudnn                     7.6.5           cuda10.1_0    anaconda
```

When I want to verify the installation:

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

The following errors are raised:

```
2021-09-01 19:44:44.950015: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-09-01 19:44:44.978949: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /app/utils/anaconda3/lib:/rruser/home/anaconda3/lib:
2021-09-01 19:44:44.979005: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-09-01 19:44:44.979070: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (klogin1): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-09-01 19:44:44.979110: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 7297103817937650454
]
```

Comment: You need to have a NVIDIA GPU and you need to install a proper driver for that GPU.

Comment: @RobertCrovella how to use the  NVIDIA GPU of the server?

Comment: Did you install the nvidia drivers? The errors points that drivers are not running.

Comment: Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH resolves the issue: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/compat/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thanks!